# Visual Studio 2008 Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I want to asking

how to make desktop app like this with Visual Studio 2008?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtAOE.jpg

I want to make some window or box when I click button number 1
I use C# programming, thank you

Comment: If you include the direct link to your image file then it can be edited into your question. Regardless of this your question may still be unclear, what have you tried/researched?

Answer (score 0):

You can go for Window forms which are available in visual studio 2008.

for more information just go through below links :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360kwx3z(v=vs.90).aspx

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdZAvW7WYJU

http://nlpdotnet.com/vstutorials/IamWhoIam.aspx